# VB6 - How could I get the ListBox selected id

Tags: listbox, vb6

AS I using the VB6.0 for create a Dialog Box with the ListBox, but only I can get the String text with Trim(DlgText$("xxxxx")), for the other side still I could not found how to get it.

Most of the answer from network said that could be using [LisBox_ID].Selected to get the item that what they want, but I can not get the same result.

For my Code:
[Dialog]

```
Function aOpenDialog As Boolean
    aOpenDialog = False
    iArrayLoop = 0
    Begin Dialog UserDialog ,,250,120,ScriptTitle,.ActivateDlgControls
        Text 5,5,130,10,"Sub Booking End Date", .tf_InsertionSetEndDate
        ListBox 5,15,100,100,aArrayList, .aArrayList
        Text 110,5,130,10,"After Date [DD-MMM-YYYY]", .tf_AfterDate
        TextBox 110,15,55,10, .txt_AfterDate
        Text 110,25,55,10,"Change Reason", .tf_ChangeReason
        TextBox 110,35,130,10, .txt_ChangeReason
        OKButton 110,45,70,10, .btn_Save
        CancelButton 110,55,70,10, .btn_Cancel
    End Dialog
    Dim dlg As UserDialog
    aArrayList(1) = "Day1"
    aArrayList(2) = "Day2"
    Dialog dlg
End Function
```

[ActiveDlgControls]

```
Function ActivateDlgControls(ControlName$, Action%, SuppValue%)
    If (Action% = 2 And ControlName$ = "btn_Save") Then
        sMissingMessage = ""
        If (Not IsDate(CStr(Trim(DlgText$("txt_AfterDate"))))) Then
            sMissingMessage = sMissingMessage & "- Please input the correct day format"
        Else
            MsgBox Format(Trim(DlgText$("txt_AfterDate")), "dd mmm yyyy")

            ' This Area will be using for get the selected array item id
            ' I can found the selected items with String
            MsgBox Trim(DlgText$("aArrayList"))

            ' Unknow way to found the selected items id
            ' MsgBox dlg.aArrayList.SelectedItem(x)
        End If

        If (sMissingMessage <> "") Then
            ActivateDlgControls = 1
            iCheckResult = 1
            sMissingMessage = "Information Missing:" & sMissingMessage
            MsgBox sMissingMessage
        End If
    ElseIf (Action% = 2 And ControlName$ = "btn_Cancel") Then
        iCheckResult = 2
    End If
End Function
```

Any idea how should I get the selected ListBox item?
I want to get the array number that I selected inside the LisBox.

Although I got an other stupid idea for get the index like as below code:

```
For iArrayLoopCheck = 0 To UBound(aArrayList)
    If (aArrayList(iArrayLoopCheck) = Trim(DlgText$("aArrayList")))Then
        MsgBox "You Select item: " & iArrayLoopCheck
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Still I was looking for any smart code/ items/ easy way to get the result quickly just like get the String value in array like: Trim(DlgText$("xxxxx"))

Best Regards,

KT

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected index of the list box:

list.ListIndex

returns 0 if the first item is selected, 1 if the second item is selected, etc., and -1 if no item is selected.

Comment: Could not be successful if I follow on it base on the object was not found.
This x.ListIndex and the x was stand for an Object Like: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235162(v=vs.60).aspx
But I cannot found which of object should I use.
But thanks you for your reply.